# Message doesn't display until something is typed in

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on a chat server, which 1 thread is for sending message, 1 thread is for display.
Currently I'm stuck. Everything works fine, except the display thread is waiting for a command to display.
For example, I type "send OtherUser hihi", the press enter.
The OtherUser console does not display anything.
However, if the OtherUser types something and press enter, then the message is display.

Are there anyways to fix this? Thank you.

If my question is not clear, can you please comment so I can re-phrase it. Thank you.

My code

```html
class ServerThread(Thread):
 
def __init__(self,socket):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.socket = socket
    
    print ("New thread started for write")

def run(self):
    while True:
        try:
            command = input("Enter command: ")
            self.socket.send(bytes(str(command), "utf8"))
            #chat=self.socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode("utf8")
            #print(chat)
        except OSError:
            continue

class ServerThreadread(Thread):
 
def __init__(self,socket):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.socket = socket     
    print("New thread started for chat display")

def run(self):
    
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s2.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT2))
    s2.setblocking(0)
    while True:
        try:
            chat=s2.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode("utf8")
            print(chat)
            #time.sleep(5)
        except OSError:
            continue
```

Comment: It may come from the `print(chat)` not flushing. Try `print(chat,flush=True)`.